# htaccess redirect to child directory and prevent child directory being callable in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

If I have a web root with `/.htaccess` like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And `/public/.haccess` like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>
```

Generally all requests forwarded to `public/*` etc. (and I can manage all the issues on this front).

**But**

How can I stop users being about to view /public as:

> //example.com/public/
>   //example.com/public/foo
>   etc.

For example, with the above configuration:

> //example.com/public/foo
>   //example.com/public/index.php
>   etc. would load...

But I'd want those requests to direct to URLs like:

> //example.com/foo
>   //example.com/index.php

i.e. as well as forwarding into the child directory `/public`, I wish to omit it from any URL, ideally by `301/302` redirection.

How can I do this via `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0):

To simply restrict direct access, `public` directory.

You can try following:

**/public/.htaccess**

```
deny from all
```

Comment: Sorry I think you've missed my point, the files are in /public, won't that stop them being served all together? I'm keen to serve them via the RewriteRule, but block the /public URL possibility.